# Django-mptt not listing names in templates

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

i am using django-mptt library to build a category tree. when i put the code below in my template i get this error.

index.html

```
{% load mptt_tags %}{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul class="root">
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

this is the error i get.

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /

Failed lookup for key [nodes] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'listing': <TreeQuerySet [<Category: Clothes>, <Category: Children Clothes>, <Category: Mens Clothes>, <Category: Womens Clothes>, <Category: Electronics>, <Category: Foods>]>}]
```

view.py

def index(request):
listing=Category.objects.all()

```
context={
    'listing':listing
}
return render(request,'catalog/index.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your template variable is `listing`, not `nodes`:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul class="root">
    {% recursetree listing %}
        …
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```